# Javascript: Interpolating variables inside strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery code which loads the `#content` div from *another* page, into the `#result` div on the *current* page:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
  $('#result').load('abother_page.html #content');
});
```

As you can see, I'm hard-coding the name of the requested file, along with the specific div I want to display, into the string that is sent with the load method.

I'm trying to make this dynamic, but my code is missing something:

```
// get the href of the link that was clicked
var href=$(this).attr('href');
// pass the href with the load method
$('#result').load('href #content');
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the href variable that i've created is not interpolated in the string. How can I do that?

I tried the following, all without success:

```
// Ruby-style: 
$('#result').load('#{href} #content');
// Concatenating-style
$('#result').load(href + '#content');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add a space indicated by "here":

```
$('#result').load(href + ' #content');
                          ^---- here
```

---

an explanation of the failed attempts are as follows:

```
//this code used the string "href" as the url
$('#result').load('href #content');

//javascript doesn't have this syntax for wrapping variables like in PHP
$('#result').load('#{href} #content');

//this code appended "#content" like it was a hash tag
$('#result').load(href + '#content');
```

Comment: Doh, thanks! This fixes the problem, and thanks a lot for your explanations, that really makes it a lot clearer now

Answer (score 0):

This has changed.

From 2015 in `ES6` this is possible now using `Template literals` there is way you can read more about on this [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

**Expression interpolation**

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log('Fifteen is ' + (a + b) + ' and\nnot ' + (2 * a + b) + '.');
// "Fifteen is 15 and
// not 20."
```

**In you case**

```
// get the href of the link that was clicked
var href=$(this).attr('href');
// pass the href with the load method
$('#result').load(`${href} #content`);
```